# Looping over a list of cell models in Python

Tags: python

I have two data sets

1. Mutations in 10 genes
2. Gene expression in 18 cancer 3D models

*For every (mutation, gene) and gene expression pair we run an ANOVA test*

This is my data

```r
> mut=read.delim("mut.tsv",row.names = 1)
> expr=as.data.frame(t(read.delim("expr.tsv",row.names = 1)))

dput(expr)

structure(list(GeneA_KO = c(0.0756383119639074, -0.162841965682723, 
-0.110703100204517, -0.457154616239399, -0.505815193885352, 0.366072775033448, 
0.288650458935083, -0.0287646498640309, -0.690732824311905, 0.157366122620995, 
-1.29451546737684, 0.124167425460344, -0.168045313861751, 0.0186504943306465, 
-0.495880827400706, -0.206668627339351, -0.148609490335447, 0.066844529089804
), GeneB_KO = c(-0.870157285953621, -0.35900872537626, -0.990406888128838, 
-0.120656981579292, -1.41427631791049, -0.866421095836781, -0.816936112146099, 
-0.894597236248507, -1.00084584207823, -0.850754488133456, -1.05314239761653, 
-1.07580675428372, -1.24708324665688, -1.04098460460899, -0.232388675985086, 
-1.48513703581865, -1.48373348870346, -1.76484058374354), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("ModelM", 
"ModelO", "ModelS", "ModelA", "ModelI", "ModelC", "ModelT", "ModelH", 
"ModelE", "ModelR", "ModelA2", "ModelP", "ModelE2", "ModelU", 
"ModelT2", "ModelC2", "ModelS2", "ModelX"))

dput(mut)

structure(list(ModelM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), ModelO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelS = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelI = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), ModelC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), ModelT = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), ModelH = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), ModelE = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), ModelR = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), ModelA2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), ModelP = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), ModelE2 = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelU = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ModelT2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelI2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), ModelC2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    ModelS2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene1_mut", 
"Gene2_mut", "Gene3_mut", "Gene4_mut", "Gene5_mut", "Gene6_mut", 
"Gene7_mut", "Gene8_mut", "Gene9_mut", "Gene10_mut"))
```

To test this, for the first 3D cancer model as instance, I have done like below

```
           GeneA_KO   GeneB_KO
ModelM   0.07563831 -0.8701573
ModelO  -0.16284197 -0.3590087
ModelS  -0.11070310 -0.9904069
ModelA  -0.45715462 -0.1206570
ModelI  -0.50581519 -1.4142763
ModelC   0.36607278 -0.8664211
ModelT   0.28865046 -0.8169361
ModelH  -0.02876465 -0.8945972
ModelE  -0.69073282 -1.0008458
ModelR   0.15736612 -0.8507545
ModelA2 -1.29451547 -1.0531424
ModelP   0.12416743 -1.0758068
ModelE2 -0.16804531 -1.2470832
ModelU   0.01865049 -1.0409846
ModelT2 -0.49588083 -0.2323887
ModelC2 -0.20666863 -1.4851370
ModelS2 -0.14860949 -1.4837335
ModelX   0.06684453 -1.7648406
```

```
           ModelM ModelO ModelS ModelA ModelI ModelC ModelT ModelH ModelE
Gene1_mut       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1
Gene2_mut       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
Gene3_mut       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
Gene4_mut       1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0
Gene5_mut       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
Gene6_mut       0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0
Gene7_mut       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
Gene8_mut       0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0
Gene9_mut       0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0
Gene10_mut      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
           ModelR ModelA2 ModelP ModelE2 ModelU ModelT2 ModelI2 ModelC2 ModelS2
Gene1_mut       1       0      0       1      1       0       1       1       0
Gene2_mut       0       0      0       0      0       0       0       1       1
Gene3_mut       0       0      0       0      1       0       0       0       0
Gene4_mut       1       1      1       1      1       1       1       0       1
Gene5_mut       0       0      0       0      0       0       0       0       1
Gene6_mut       0       0      0       1      1       0       0       1       1
Gene7_mut       1       0      0       0      0       0       0       0       1
Gene8_mut       0       0      0       0      1       0       0       1       0
Gene9_mut       1       0      0       0      1       0       0       0       0
Gene10_mut      0       0      1       0      1       0       0       0       1
```

```
> my_data=cbind(mut[,1],expr[,1])
> colnames(my_data)=c("mut","expr")
> res.aov <- aov(expr ~ mut, data = as.data.frame(my_data))
> # Summary of the analysis
> summary(res.aov)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
mut          1  0.145  0.1448   0.192  0.673
Residuals    8  6.022  0.7527
```

Now I do a for loop for all of the 18 cancer cell lines

```
> for(i in 1:ncol(g))
+ {
+   my_data=as.data.frame(cbind(m[,1],g[,1]))
+   #tidy will summarise and return neat format
+   print(broom::tidy(aov(my_data[,2] ~ my_data[,1], data = my_data)))
+ }
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.145  0.145     0.192   0.673
2 Residuals        8 6.02   0.753    NA      NA    
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.145  0.145     0.192   0.673
2 Residuals        8 6.02   0.753    NA      NA
```

I done this in R but of course I got when doing in Python

*Python*

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import statsmodels.api as sm
os.getcwd()
os.chdir("/Users//Downloads/test")
os.getcwd()
m = pd.read_csv("mut.tsv", sep="\t", index_col=0,delim_whitespace=True)
m=pd.DataFrame(m)
m
g = pd.read_csv("expr.tsv", sep="\t",index_col=0,delim_whitespace=True).T
g=pd.DataFrame(g)
g
lst = list(g.columns)

lst
dfs = []
for Model in lst:
   dfs.append(pd.concat([m.iloc[:, 0].reset_index(drop=True), g.iloc[0,:].reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1))
   dfs.append(df.dropna())
   dfs.append(df.columns==['mut','expr'])
   model = ols('expr ~ C(mut)', data=df).fit()
   aov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)
   aov_table
   final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

```
    for Model in lst:
      Input In [165]
        for Model in lst:
                         ^
    IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

[image]

Comment: When asking about errors, please remember to _always_ include the actual error. We cannot help you debug errors you don't share.

Comment: thank you, I have added the error in my main post

Comment: @Angel, you still did not include the error that you get when you are using R. Anyway, why would you define `i` in your loop and not use it? And when it comes to the `Python` error, it is obvious!

Comment: Thank you @haci I get error in Python part only. The R code is OK

Comment: Thanks I have edited my post so I believe the R code will run smoothly. I have added the desire output from R code to the post. First, I have tried for one sample then using a for loop to doing one-way ANOVA over 18 samples. But, I do not know how to do this by Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one potential approach:

Example data:

```r
expr1 <- structure(list(GeneA_KO = c(0.0756383119639074, -0.162841965682723, -0.110703100204517, -0.457154616239399, -0.505815193885352, 0.366072775033448, 0.288650458935083, -0.0287646498640309, -0.690732824311905, 0.157366122620995, -1.29451546737684, 0.124167425460344, -0.168045313861751, 0.0186504943306465, -0.495880827400706, -0.206668627339351, -0.148609490335447, 0.066844529089804), GeneB_KO = c(-0.870157285953621, -0.35900872537626, -0.990406888128838, -0.120656981579292, -1.41427631791049, -0.866421095836781, -0.816936112146099, -0.894597236248507, -1.00084584207823, -0.850754488133456, -1.05314239761653, -1.07580675428372, -1.24708324665688, -1.04098460460899, -0.232388675985086, -1.48513703581865, -1.48373348870346, -1.76484058374354)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("ModelM", "ModelO", "ModelS", "ModelA", "ModelI", "ModelC", "ModelT", "ModelH", "ModelE", "ModelR", "ModelA2", "ModelP", "ModelE2", "ModelU", "ModelT2", "ModelC2", "ModelS2", "ModelX"))
mut <- structure(list(ModelM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelS = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelI = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelC = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelT = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), ModelH = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), ModelE = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), ModelR = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), ModelA2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelP = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), ModelE2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelU = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), ModelT2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelI2 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ModelC2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L),     ModelS2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene1_mut", "Gene2_mut", "Gene3_mut", "Gene4_mut", "Gene5_mut", "Gene6_mut", "Gene7_mut", "Gene8_mut", "Gene9_mut", "Gene10_mut"))
```

---

R code:

```r
my_data=cbind(mut[,1],expr1[1:10,1])
colnames(my_data)=c("mut","expr1")
res.aov <- aov(expr1 ~ mut, data = as.data.frame(my_data))
summary(res.aov)
#>             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
#> mut          1 0.1364  0.1364   1.114  0.322
#> Residuals    8 0.9789  0.1224

for (j in 1:nrow(mut)) {
  for(i in 1:ncol(expr1)) {
    my_data=as.data.frame(cbind(mut[,j],expr1[1:10,i]))
    print(broom::tidy(aov(my_data[,2] ~ my_data[,1], data = my_data)))
  }
}
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.136  0.136      1.11   0.322
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.979  0.122     NA     NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.541 0.541       7.38  0.0264
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.587 0.0733     NA    NA     
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.136  0.136      1.11   0.322
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.979  0.122     NA     NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.541 0.541       7.38  0.0264
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.587 0.0733     NA    NA     
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.136  0.136      1.11   0.322
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.979  0.122     NA     NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.541 0.541       7.38  0.0264
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.587 0.0733     NA    NA     
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.136  0.136      1.11   0.322
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.979  0.122     NA     NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.541 0.541       7.38  0.0264
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.587 0.0733     NA    NA     
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.136  0.136      1.11   0.322
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.979  0.122     NA     NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.541 0.541       7.38  0.0264
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.587 0.0733     NA    NA     
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.136  0.136      1.11   0.322
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.979  0.122     NA     NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.541 0.541       7.38  0.0264
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.587 0.0733     NA    NA     
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df  sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.0612 0.0612     0.465   0.515
#> 2 Residuals        8 1.05   0.132     NA      NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df  sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.0637 0.0637     0.479   0.508
#> 2 Residuals        8 1.06   0.133     NA      NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.246  0.246      2.26   0.171
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.869  0.109     NA     NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.313  0.313      3.07   0.118
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.815  0.102     NA     NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df   sumsq  meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.00108 0.00108   0.00777   0.932
#> 2 Residuals        8 1.11    0.139    NA        NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.220  0.220      1.94   0.201
#> 2 Residuals        8 0.907  0.113     NA     NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df  sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.0529 0.0529     0.398   0.546
#> 2 Residuals        8 1.06   0.133     NA      NA    
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   term            df  sumsq meansq statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 my_data[, 1]     1 0.0901 0.0901     0.695   0.429
#> 2 Residuals        8 1.04   0.130     NA      NA

# write.csv(mut, "mut.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
# write.csv(expr1[1:10,], "expr1.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Python code:

````py
import os
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import statsmodels.api as sm
m = pd.read_csv("mut.csv", sep=",")
m=pd.DataFrame(m)
m.info()
g = pd.read_csv("expr1.csv", sep=",")
g=pd.DataFrame(g)

lst = list(g.columns)
m_lst = list(m.columns)

dfs = pd.DataFrame({})
for Mut in m_lst:
    for Model in lst:
        df = pd.concat([m[[Mut]].reset_index(drop=True), g[[Model]].reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
        df = df.rename(columns={Mut: "mut", Model: "g"})
        model = ols('g ~ C(mut)', data=df).fit()
        aov_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)
        aov_table[['Model']] = Model
        aov_table[['Mut']] = Mut
        dfs = dfs.append(aov_table)

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):
    print(dfs)
            sum_sq   df         F    PR(>F)     Model      Mut
C(mut)    0.136365  1.0  1.114460  0.321950  GeneA_KO   ModelM
Residual  0.978877  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelM
C(mut)    0.540949  1.0  7.375925  0.026417  GeneB_KO   ModelM
Residual  0.586718  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelM
C(mut)    0.136365  1.0  1.114460  0.321950  GeneA_KO   ModelO
Residual  0.978877  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelO
C(mut)    0.540949  1.0  7.375925  0.026417  GeneB_KO   ModelO
Residual  0.586718  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelO
C(mut)    0.136365  1.0  1.114460  0.321950  GeneA_KO   ModelS
Residual  0.978877  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelS
C(mut)    0.540949  1.0  7.375925  0.026417  GeneB_KO   ModelS
Residual  0.586718  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelS
C(mut)    0.136365  1.0  1.114460  0.321950  GeneA_KO   ModelA
Residual  0.978877  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelA
C(mut)    0.540949  1.0  7.375925  0.026417  GeneB_KO   ModelA
Residual  0.586718  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelA
C(mut)    0.136365  1.0  1.114460  0.321950  GeneA_KO   ModelI
Residual  0.978877  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelI
C(mut)    0.540949  1.0  7.375925  0.026417  GeneB_KO   ModelI
Residual  0.586718  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelI
C(mut)    0.136365  1.0  1.114460  0.321950  GeneA_KO   ModelC
Residual  0.978877  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelC
C(mut)    0.540949  1.0  7.375925  0.026417  GeneB_KO   ModelC
Residual  0.586718  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelC
C(mut)    0.061205  1.0  0.464539  0.514753  GeneA_KO   ModelT
Residual  1.054037  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelT
C(mut)    0.063734  1.0  0.479234  0.508361  GeneB_KO   ModelT
Residual  1.063933  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelT
C(mut)    0.245964  1.0  2.263619  0.170857  GeneA_KO   ModelH
Residual  0.869278  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelH
C(mut)    0.312937  1.0  3.072788  0.117706  GeneB_KO   ModelH
Residual  0.814730  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelH
C(mut)    0.001082  1.0  0.007771  0.931920  GeneA_KO   ModelE
Residual  1.114159  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelE
C(mut)    0.220171  1.0  1.940909  0.201060  GeneB_KO   ModelE
Residual  0.907496  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelE
C(mut)    0.052891  1.0  0.398296  0.545575  GeneA_KO   ModelR
Residual  1.062350  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelR
C(mut)    0.090105  1.0  0.694741  0.428739  GeneB_KO   ModelR
Residual  1.037562  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelR
C(mut)    0.136365  1.0  1.114460  0.321950  GeneA_KO  ModelA2
Residual  0.978877  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO  ModelA2
C(mut)    0.540949  1.0  7.375925  0.026417  GeneB_KO  ModelA2
Residual  0.586718  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO  ModelA2
C(mut)    0.004637  1.0  0.033399  0.859537  GeneA_KO   ModelP
Residual  1.110605  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelP
C(mut)    0.276724  1.0  2.601573  0.145422  GeneB_KO   ModelP
Residual  0.850943  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelP
C(mut)    0.044310  1.0  0.331000  0.580888  GeneA_KO  ModelE2
Residual  1.070932  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO  ModelE2
C(mut)    0.170278  1.0  1.422852  0.267110  GeneB_KO  ModelE2
Residual  0.957389  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO  ModelE2
C(mut)    0.001687  1.0  0.012120  0.915049  GeneA_KO   ModelU
Residual  1.113555  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO   ModelU
C(mut)    0.008679  1.0  0.062048  0.809563  GeneB_KO   ModelU
Residual  1.118988  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO   ModelU
C(mut)    0.136365  1.0  1.114460  0.321950  GeneA_KO  ModelT2
Residual  0.978877  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO  ModelT2
C(mut)    0.540949  1.0  7.375925  0.026417  GeneB_KO  ModelT2
Residual  0.586718  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO  ModelT2
C(mut)    0.017610  1.0  0.128353  0.729416  GeneA_KO  ModelI2
Residual  1.097631  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO  ModelI2
C(mut)    0.260821  1.0  2.407079  0.159387  GeneB_KO  ModelI2
Residual  0.866846  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO  ModelI2
C(mut)    0.191207  1.0  1.655405  0.234206  GeneA_KO  ModelC2
Residual  0.924035  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO  ModelC2
C(mut)    0.033474  1.0  0.244741  0.634101  GeneB_KO  ModelC2
Residual  1.094193  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO  ModelC2
C(mut)    0.044621  1.0  0.333425  0.579533  GeneA_KO  ModelS2
Residual  1.070620  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneA_KO  ModelS2
C(mut)    0.096956  1.0  0.752533  0.410940  GeneB_KO  ModelS2
Residual  1.030711  8.0       NaN       NaN  GeneB_KO  ModelS2
```
````

Comment: Sorry I was running your python code but I get this error for Mut in m_lst:
  Input In [81]
    for Mut in m_lst:
                     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: The `IndentationError` means you haven't got the correct whitespace - you need 4 spaces in front of each indented line @Angel and no whitespace in front of 'non-indented' lines (basically, copy it exactly as I have it in my answer and it will work)

Comment: Thanks a lot that's weird I just copied and pasted that but gives error

Comment: You're using spyder, so perhaps try going to "Source --> Fix Indentation" and see if your code changes and if the error persists

Comment: Source fixed Indentation error now I get this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/angel/Downloads/test/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    model = ols('g ~ C(mut)', data=df).fit()
  File "/Users/angel/Downloads/docker/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 209, in from_formula
    raise ValueError('endog has evaluated to an array with multiple '
ValueError: endog has evaluated to an array with multiple columns that has shape (10, 18). This occurs when the variable converted to endog is non-numeric (e.g., bool or str).

Comment: That error is harder to understand, sorry @Angel; I think you should post another question with a reproducible example showing how you got that error so we can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Before using this-->  `with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):`,  `print(dfs)` could display the 1st 10 rows,  tried, worked!

Comment: Moreover, after using this--> `python -V`,  my z shell on my macbook air is using Python 3.9.16 .

Comment: Apparently the `pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None)` approach doesn't work with jupyter notebooks; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424493/pandas-setting-no-of-max-rows for more details @envs_h_gang_5